# Java uses object as monitor, isn't that object too heavy weight?

Tags: java, multithreading

I read this in Java language Spec 17.1:

> "Each object in Java is associated
>   with a monitor, which a thread can
>   lock or unlock."

Why necessarily? Doesn't that make java object too heavy weight? I've no idea why a Object like, say, a string, should be naturally a monitor!

EDIT:

I think it over and yes, Java has a keyword **synchronized**, because **EVERY** object could have a synchronized method, so it's necessary to associate **EVERY** object a Monitor.

But still this seems not a very good solution, usually you need more that one mutex for one class, except for that pojo classes that's really very simple.

Comment: Just because every object is associated with a monitor in the language spec doesn't mean that the monitor exists until it is used. I would expect that most runtimes would not create a monitor for an object until it is the subject of a `synchronized` block/method.

Comment: but how? when a class is loaded search through all its methods to see if it use synchronized(this)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fundamental problem is in assuming that every object has some sort of `Monitor` built into it, waiting for it to be used by some code. In reality, most objects are never used as a monitor, so the monitors don't have to be created until they are used. Rather than implementing this feature as every object having a `private Monitor monitor` field, think of it as being implemented as the JVM having a global `HashMap<object, Monitor> monitors`.

A possible implementation is this: Whenever a `synchronized` block is entered, the JVM looks up the synchronized object in the map (`monitors`). If it finds it, it gets the monitor to use. If it doesn't find it, it enters a critical section dedicated to the map. It then looks up the object again because another thread may have created it between the previous check and entering the critical section. If it's still not there, it creates the monitor for the synchronized object and leaves the critical section.

Comment: I agree in this way it could work, although still not sure if it really work in this way.

Comment: As far as I know, this strategy was used in older JVMs but was discarded because it creates a bottleneck as you must synchronize access to the same `HashMap` for *every* monitor. Nowadays it is used when you need to trade speed/parallelism for space efficiency.

Comment: @Gabe What do you mean by "it enters a critical section dedicated to the map." . Can you elaborate on this ?

Comment: @Geek: This putative HashMap would have its own lock which would would be used to synchronize write access to it.

Answer (score 4):

There is some truth in your assumptions, in the classical book "Java Concurrency in Practice" (written by the gurus Brian Goetz, Tim Peierls, Joshua Bloch, Joseph Bowbeer, David Holmes, Doug Lea) they write:

> The fact that every object has a built-in lock is just a convenience
>   so that you needn't explicitly create lock objects. In retrospect,
>   this design decision was probably a bad one: not only can it be
>   confusing, but it forces JVM implementors to make tradeoffs between
>   object size and locking performance.

(chapter 2.4.: Guarding State with Locks)

Comment: I'm having exactly the same feeling here. Some of the answers above says that you can create a lock when you need it, it's obviously not practical because the test whether you have a lock need some sort of synchronization which is provided by a lock.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty smart way to make virtually **everything** thread-safe. I think heavy weight is somewhat subjective; in Java, for example, the object only gains a notifiable wait queue, while specifying mutual exclusion is explicitly done with `synchronize`.

C# uses a similar method to enforce thread safety, so clearly MS also thought it was a pretty clever solution. The alternative is what? Hand-written semaphores and mutexes? In Java, that would be a nightmare, considering most production-level apps (i.e. servers, services, etc) *have* to be multi-threaded. Having the language do all that tough/boring stuff for you is kind of awesome.

Comment: Seems this a monitor is not assigned for C# objects. Microsoft is doing it differently. See the link below. Microsoft use separate class Monitor for thread synchronization.

Comment: In Java, this support is in three main forms:
a mutex variable is associated with every object; there is a set of methods defined on Object that
support coordination of threads; and a set of classes in java.lang that allows programmers to
create and manage threads. Similarly, in .NET there is a Monitor (or lock) associated with every
object instance. The System.Threading namespace contains classes that allow thread creation and
manipulation.

Comment: ...Yes you are right. C# does assign a monitor for all objects.

Answer (score 0):

Thread synchronization is necessary to ensure correct outcome as their may be racing condition.

Well, if it is not as heavy as a LCD or CRT monitor, it would be fine?

Comment: Things can be necessary, doesn't mean they should be everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

not that heavy in weight. objects are cheap.

I agree that the concept that any object can be a lock is quite confusing. many people thinks that `synchronized(obj)` protects the `obj` from being accessed concurrently. if we have separate locks from states, this misconception is less likely.

not text in java memory model shows any importance of using arbitrary object, or any object, as synchronization primitives. maybe it's economical design to use objects for this purpose.

it could as well use integers as locks. `synchronized(493725)` actually since each object is associated with an integer internally (its address), JVM probably does this. There's zero overhead for objects that are not being synchronized upon.

with java.util.concurrent classes, you don't ever need such `synchronized(obj)` any more, if you dislike it.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that knowledge. However I'm confused how it's implemented in the underlying OS level? With windows API to create a mutex I'll have to call "CreateCriticalSection" to get a handle, so I'm wondering does JVM create one critical section for each object? That sounds crazy!

Comment: JVM doesn't need OS for mutex, it can have its own impl. It allocates necessary locking data structure for an object *only* when `synchronized(obj)` is executed. for objects that are never `synchronized`, no need to do anything.